# How to format/clean name of posts in my wordpress blog

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a wordpress blog with 2000 posts. Name of each post is a person's name. But the first name and last name are separated by a '-', I want to automate the process of removal of these '-' from the post names.

Example -

```
      Present name of a post:  Isaac-Newton
      Desired name          :  Isaac Newton
```

Is there any script, or code to do it, as it will be a tedious job, If I have to manually edit the names of all the posts. Any help, suggestions what might work?

Comment: Are you talking about the `post_title` or the 'post_name`, as it appears in the database? The latter is used to construct URLs (at least potentially) and you can't have spaces in URLs.

Comment: I am talking about the post_title, as it appears on my blog.

Comment: Your theme should be using the `post_title` but it could be doing something odd. When you edit a post, does the title at the top, just above the permalink, have the dashes or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could open the WP database in PhpMyadmin and run something like the following:

```
update wp_posts set post_title = replace(post_title, "-", " ") WHERE post_title LIKE '%-%';
```

Obviously backup the database first, to ensure you don't completely mess it up.

Comment: This was my thought too but it will replace all dashes, even where appropriate-- say, inside a hyphenated last name.

Comment: Sure, depends what else he has in the title I guess.

Comment: +1 Despite the possible issue I mentioned, I'd go with this answer.